# BASH multiple variables with same name in remote config file

Tags: bash, file, variables, config, external

What I am trying to do is having a config file that controls a very basic backup script.

```
#Credentials
username="backup.user"
password="****"
from="/mnt"
to="/home/backup"



#Mountpoints
n=1
source="//10.X.X.X/Public"
destination="/mnt/Public"

n=2
source="//10.X.X.X/it"
destination="/mnt/it"
```

Inside the script itself it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#getting variables from the external config file
export $(cat config.ini | grep -v ^# | xargs)

#the command I am trying to achieve
mountpoint[$n]="mount -t cifs -o username=$username,password=$password,ro $source $destination"

#mounts the array of mountpoints defined
for mountpoint in "${mountpoint[@]}";
        do
                ${mountpoint}
        done


function currentDate () {
date +%Y%m%d
}


if [ ! -d "$to/$(currentDate)" ] ; then
                mkdir "$to/$(currentDate)";
                cp --verbose -R "$from/." "$to/$(currentDate)" >> $to/$(currentDate)/fileLog.txt
                diff -qr $from $to/$(currentDate) >> $to/$(currentDate)/differencesLog.txt
else
                exit
fi
umount -a -t cifs -l /mnt/*
done
```

I am trying to do this:
**Have a set of variables in config for each mountpoint.**

A for loop for that will echo the last source and destination as normal because it doesn't know when a certain set of variables is done for "n=1".

How will you guys do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please use `source config.ini` instead of `export $(cat config.ini | grep -v ^# | xargs)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: :) What about using `json` for the config file? Wouldn't that simplify things a lot?

Comment: No problem for me, it's more of a thing to learn from while doing something useful. Just don't know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

```
# create an array
mountpoint=()
# append to the array
mountpoint+=("item 1")
mountpoint+=("item 2")
# iterate the array
for i in "${mountpoint[@]}"; do
    echo "${i}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: The thing is that I would like to have some parameters defined inside config.ini (source and destination) for every "n" object. Is it possible?